# How to use bytebuddy to intercept a "synchronized" code block in Java?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

There is a *synchronized* code block shown as below:

```
public class Counter {
  int count;  

  public void increment(){
    synchronized(this){
      this.count ++;   
    }   
  }
}
```

I know how to use bytebuddy to intercept the *instrument* method.
Can bytebuddy intercept the *synchronized* code block as well?

My ultimate goal is to inject my own code in the beginning or the end of the code block.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Byte Buddy to change code within a method; all such operations are however possible by using ASM which is exposed by Byte Buddy by using a `AsmClassVisitorWrapper` that you can register in its API.